# Unresolved externals on static linking OpenSceneGraph libraries in Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio, static-linking, openscenegraph

I'm using OpenSceneGraph libraries in my application and I want to link them statically, so I don't have to carry DLLs with binary. I have downloaded OpenSceneGraph 3.4.0 sources and generated Visual Studio project by cmake. I did disabled `DYNAMIC_OPENSCENEGRAPH` and `DYNAMIC_OPENTHREADS` in cmake GUI. After that I successfully compiled OSG and have static libraries (.lib). In my application I added include and library directories in `project properties -> VC++ Directories -> Include Directories` & `Library Directories` (I'm using Visual Studio 2013 by the way). I also added directory with OSG .lib's in `Linker -> General -> Additional Library Directories` and typed all required libs in `Linker -> Input -> Additional Dependencies`:

```
ot20-OpenThreads.lib
osg130-osg.lib
osg130-osgUtil.lib
osg130-osgGA.lib
osg130-osgDB.lib
osg130-osgViewer.lib
osg130-osgText.lib
opengl32.lib
osgdb_3ds.lib
osgdb_freetype.lib
osgdb_png.lib
```

And I'm still getting unresolved externals errors for OSG symbols. I also tried setting `General -> Character Set` to Unicode but it didn't help (in OSG project generated by cmake I have Multi-Byte Character anyway). I don't have any ideas how to solve that now, it's my first time compiling application with static linked libraries.

I would really appreciate any help.

P.s. Sorry for no code, I can't provide it but I try to give as much details as I can. With dynamic linking I can build my application without any problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to solve this problem myself.
I was missing two more libraries in `Linker -> Input -> Additional Dependencies`:

```
msvcrt.lib
libcmt.lib
```

And I also had to add preprocessor definition `OSG_LIBRARY_STATIC` in `C/C++ -> Preprocessor -> Preprocessor Definitions`. The last thing was adding these few lines of code in my main.cpp to link OSG plugins:

```
#ifdef OSG_LIBRARY_STATIC
    USE_OSGPLUGIN(freetype)
    USE_OSGPLUGIN(png)
    USE_OSGPLUGIN(3ds)
#endif
```

Now my application is successfully compiling and working :)

P.s. On first build I had errors with PNG and FreeType plugins which were caused by lack of .lib-s for libpng and freetype. There errors were solved in my case by adding `libpng16_static.lib` and `freetype250.lib` to `Linker -> Input -> Additional Dependencies` and copying them into my libraries directory (obviously other plugins would depend on other libraries).

Comment: Brilliant answer! It helped a lot.
Btw, it is worth to add about required header to use USE_OSGPLUGIN macro:

```#include <osgDB/Registry>```